# Is the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test appropriate when the Brier score is the accuracy metric?

Tags: random-forest, statistical-power, model-comparison, wilcoxon-signed-rank, scoring-rules

When comparing model performance, is it valid to use the Wilcoxon signed rank test for matched pairs, when the accuracy metric is the Brier score?

(Here, the Brier score is used in calculating the OOB error, which is available using the Ranger RF package - but this question is asked in general terms. I'm comparing two random forest models on the same data data - where each has a different set of variables available.)

I see many journal articles using AUC with the Wilcoxon test. Wilcoxon tests using the Brier score are scarce, but they exist.

This question isn't about the best way to compare models, rather, is it asking if it's okay to use a Brier score with the Wilcoxon signed rank test.

Comment: Why don't you think it would be valid? Ultimately it compares two sample-derived statistics.

Comment: Because it's hard to find.  Maybe the Brier distribution is irregular?  Probably not, just an idea.

Comment: Hmm... even if we accept it is, we test the hypothesis of zero median for the difference between paired samples. The main assumption is that the distribution of the differences is symmetric (not Brier score itself). Do you have reasons to doubt that?